# Understanding simple ProgressDialogue , how can another thread update UI?

Tags: dialog, progressdialog, android

This example is copied from a book on Android. As you can see from my question, I am new to Android and trying to understand. **This application should crash but it does not** (I am updating UI from another thread. Which is not allowed.It should cause a crash. It does not. Why?). My code is:

```
final ProgressDialog dialogue = ProgressDialog.show(this, "title", "message");

       new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                dialogue.dismiss();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }
    }).start();
```

This is done in `OnCreate` function. I am confused with line - `dialogue.dismiss();` Isn't that updating UI (dismissing dialogue) from another thread? Why does this app **not** cause segmentation fault?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cant `dismiss()` it in run method because it is `non UI thread`.and if you want to dismiss then use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).And its better to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question or I misunderstood your answer. This app does NOT crash even though I am updating UI from other thread.I want to know why does it NOT crash.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is correct only man.You are starting a thread using the .start function and after that the run function called and then after 7 seconds the the dialogue will dismiss.The dialogue.dismiss() is used to dismiss the dialogue.If you will not call dismiss(),the progress bar never dismissed.You can check by commenting the line Thread.sleep(7000).

Comment: That is correct but I am updating UI from another thread. Which is not allowed.It should cause a crash. It does not. Why?